# Entity Framework: Is it possible to insert the id of a newly created record into another record while running Seed method

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

I'm having issues when attempting to use the id created on one record for multiple records.

My models look like this:

```
public class Student 
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int StudentId { get; set; }

    public int PersonId { get; set; }

    public string SID { get; set; }   

    public int AccountId { get; set; }

    public bool Active { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PersonId")]
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AccountId")]
    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string MI { get; set; }
    public int SSN { get; set; }
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public int RaceId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AddressId")]
    public Address Addresss { get; set; }  
}

 public class Address
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public string StreetAddress { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public int ZipCode { get; set; }
}
```

using the following to seed the database:

```
context.Students.AddOrUpdate(x => x.SID,
    new WestCobb.Data.Student
    {
        SID = "99-B50-404324175",
        EnrollmentDate = Convert.ToDateTime("01-30-2017"),
        Active = true,
        Person = new WestCobb.Data.Person
        {
            FirstName = "Brian",
            LastName = "Folks",
            AddressId = 4,
            SSN = 404324175,
            Addresss = new WestCobb.Data.Address // This address!
            {
                StreetAddress = "5076 Lake Charles Court",
                City = "Chicago",
                State = "Illinois",
                ZipCode = 60208
            }
        },
        Account = new WestCobb.Data.Account
        {
            AccountNumber = "M00000000000088",
            AccountTypeId = 1,
            Priority = 1,
            Rate = 225.00m,
            BillingCycleId = 1,
            CreateDate = Convert.ToDateTime("01-30-2017"),
            Active = true
        }
    },
    // Manually set AddressId of this Person to AddressId of previous Person added 
    new WestCobb.Data.Student
    {
        SID = "99-A50-404527896",
        EnrollmentDate = Convert.ToDateTime("01-30-2017"),
        Active = true,
        Person = new WestCobb.Data.Person
        {
            FirstName = "Arthur",
            LastName = "Clue",
            SSN = 404527896,
            AddressId = context.Addresses.Last().AddressId // This seems not to work
        },
        Account = new WestCobb.Data.Account
        {
            AccountNumber = "W89322198433588",
            AccountTypeId = 1,
            Priority = 2,
            Rate = 225.00m,
            BillingCycleId = 1,
            CreateDate = Convert.ToDateTime("01-30-2017"),
            Active = true
        }
    }
);
```

and getting the following error:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'WestCobb.Data.Address Last[Address](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[WestCobb.Data.Address])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

Is it possible to use the same "id" (AddressId) that was created from the insertion of the first Person's address in the Address of the second Person?  I want to use the same Id for the AddressId of multiple Persons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the same Address entity to multiple Persons, why don't you create the Address first, then use it as many times as you want ?

```
var myAwesomeAddress = new WestCobb.Data.Address()
{
    StreetAddress = "5076 Lake Charles Court",
    City = "Chicago",
    State = "Illinois",
    ZipCode = 60208
};

// You should have a DbSet of your Addresses right ?
context.Addresses.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Id, // Use any discriminator
    myAwesomeAddress
);

context.Students.AddOrUpdate(x => x.SID,
    new WestCobb.Data.Student
    {
        SID = "99-B50-404324175",
        EnrollmentDate = Convert.ToDateTime("01-30-2017"),
        Active = true,
        Person = new WestCobb.Data.Person
        {
            FirstName = "Brian",
            LastName = "Folks",
            AddressId = 4,
            SSN = 404324175,
            Addresss = myAwesomeAddress
        }
    },
    new WestCobb.Data.Student
    {
        SID = "99-A50-404527896",
        EnrollmentDate = Convert.ToDateTime("01-30-2017"),
        Active = true,
        Person = new WestCobb.Data.Person
        {
            FirstName = "Arthur",
            LastName = "Clue",
            SSN = 404527896,
            Address = myAwesomeAddress // here
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Awesome Sauce! This actually gives me much more flexibility than the inline method.  Good suggestion thanks!!